# Logic gate simplification

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Hi I was building different logic gates using only the **NOR gate**
However, I was very confused with the answers people got for example.

Anyway the image shows an implementation of **NAND gate using NOR Gates**

The top part of the image shows how everyone else gets NAND from using NOR

The bottom part of the image is what I think It can be simplified to. Please tell me if what I have done is correct thanks.

[image: This is what I got]

Comment: Better right it down as a formula.

Answer (score 1):

Your alternative circuit computes `NOT(NOT(A NOR B))`, which the same as NOR rather than NAND.

Your computation has an error in very the first step where you represent `A NOR B` as $\overline A+\overline B$ -- it should be $\overline{A+B}$.